# CSS Issue in IE: Sidebar Won't Appear

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

Having trouble diagnosing/fixing an issue on a website where the Wordpress sidebar won't appear in Internet Explorer (all versions).

Here's a link to one of the affected pages:

http://piiholozipline.com/tours

In Firefox/Safari, the sidebar is visible. In IE, it's hidden.

Comment: Your website looks the same in FF8 and IE9.

Comment: are you in compatibility mode in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do so this:

```css
#content_box{
    position:relative;
}

.custom #sidebars {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:690px
}
```